# node js crypto.PBKDF2Sync behaves differently in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I recently switched to Ubuntu 14.04, and also worked on my Mac machine. This project is cloned from the same repo, but behaves differently on two machines. I have no clue why, please help me.

I used this line to hashed my password, and it works fine on my mac machine.

```
var hashed = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(entered,this.salt,12000,128).toString('hex');
```

However, in Ubuntu, it gives following errors:

```
    > node ./bin/www


crypto.js:574
    var ret = binding.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest);
                      ^

TypeError: Not a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:574:23)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:553:10)
    at model.<anonymous> (/media/linux/app/dataModel/userModel.js:30:33)
    at _next (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
    at fnWrapper (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
    at model.Object.defineProperty.value.fn (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:215:9)
    at _next (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
    at fnWrapper (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
    at /media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:198:13
    at complete (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1107:5)
    at /media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1133:20
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:645:22)
    at /media/linux/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1129:9
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:336:13)

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bocerapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/linux/app/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance!